# After visiting my site I have to refresh for new content. I use cloudfront

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a WordPress website on AWS with 2 EC2 instances behind a load balancer. Then I have CloudFront directing to that load balancer and S3 handles my images.

We publish articles daily. When I visit the site, I then need need to reload the page to see new articles.

I set all of this up. However, I do not know CloudFront well enough to know how to diagnose or solve the issue. I'm only assuming it is CloudFront as no other caching tools are in use.

If it is CloudFront, what might be the issue? If not, then how should I proceed to solve this?

Comment: *When I visit the site, I then need need to reload the page to see new articles.* there are several caveats on CloudFlare caching, the configuration on CloudFlare itself (which pretty restricted on free mode), cache headers, etc. you can dig some on [their KB](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-). also, i feel this more into networking problem.. than programming issue.

Comment: Thanks Bagus but I am using AWS CloudFront rather than CloudFlare.
When I used CloudFlare in the past (months ago) it was actually fine..

Comment: wah my bad, i misread that Cloud"Front" as Cloud"Flare". but the idea is the same, double check the CDN provider cache configuration and your website cache-related headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by setting the TTL from the origin and just telling CloudFront to use the origin's cache headers.

Alternatively, you can do this just in CloudFront directly by

- setting the behavior of index.html to be 0 TTL (leave all other settings the same)
  and
- the default behavior for everything else *, and set the TTL to be whatever you prefer.

[Path Patterns for Cache Behaviours](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior)  is a very useful article

Comment: I found I had set it up to use origin cache headers. I then looked at my expires-by rules and saw 1 month for text/html. I changed that to 4 hours and will see if that does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I faced the same issue with Cloudfront. This is an issue regarding object caching in Cloudfront. So, firstly [go to this url](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/) And then setup cloudfront accordingly and point to your Load Balancer.

If you have done so, previously then you need to configure .htaccess files to set these headers. I think currently You have 300 seconds or more to cache objects.

So, what's happening is your website is cached for 300 seconds and you have to refresh it to view the new content.

This thing can also be solved by using caching plugins like breeze or you can use LiteSpeed webserver which is 5x faster than any other webserver with their own caching plugin. I prefer the second method because LiteSpeed helps me speed up my website and handles a lot of traffic like 5M+ traffic per month on a $5 Lightsail VPS or $10 Ec2 (t2.micro instance).

Apply these techniques and tell me if it works or I will tell you other methods. Remember the best thing is to use a caching plugin I would recommend Breeze and use the ttl of that caching plugin in CloudFront. Or you can simply use Litespeed webserver to reduce your AWS cost and resolve this issue permanently.